# The call to other actions does not work correctly with TYPO3 Extbase

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a contoller that it calls SocialProfile with one action for get the profile of Twitter, Facebook or Google+ and save the SocialProfile object, each one. The end of this action calls the edit action with the objective of the end user add groups of categories (not TYPO3 category), the problem is the second action does not work correctly.

I have been using this instruction for calls `editAction` at the end of `createAction`

```
$this->redirect('edit', null, null, array('profileid' => "{$profileid}"),11);
```

Now the `editAction`

```
public function editAction( $socialProfile = NULL)
    {
        $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
        var_dump($arguments);
        $groups = Enum\GruposContenidos::categoryGroupList();
        $this->view->assign('categoryGroups', $groups);
        $this->view->assign('socialProfile', $socialProfile);
    }
```

The error is next

> Required argument "socialProfile" is not set for Vendor\Extension\Controller\SocialProfileController->edit. exception code:1298012500

I have identicated in the URL that `editAction` method runs but does not show the `var_dump`. I follow the error code in TYPO3 (https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/Flow/1298012500) and I have tried many changes but does not work.

What is the correct way to call this type of actions or is it possible to use something like `redirect` sending parameters?

The `editAction` works well when it is called from the action list through Fluid and lets change the category values.

It is beeing develop in TYPO3 7.6 and PHP 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `$this->redirect('edit', null, null, array('socialProfile' => $socialProfile),11);` and pass the whole SocialProfile object rather than its ID? Generally, you need to match the two names.

Comment: I have another problem when I try to pass the SocialProfile object `Could not serialize Domain Object .... It is neither an Entity with identity properties set, nor a Value Object. exception code:1260881688` the problem is that I do not have th UID. I will try with `persistAll` in repository. About the names, it is not necessary match the two names, because the structure is ` 'key' => value` , in sometimes I prefer to use different names, for example to separate Fluid than Extbase.

Comment: Maybe you could try `$this->forward()`, so you don't need to persist the `$socialProfile`, while your `editAction()` can still use it. For the names, I mean the `key` should match the parameter name in your action, like `array('socialProfile' => $SocialProfile)` with `public function editAction( $socialProfile = NULL)`, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can var_dump inside the initializeEditAction.

pls try:

```
$this->redirect('edit', null, null, array('profileid' => $profileid),11);
```

can you show me the annotations from the editAction and unistall and install the extension one time. Annotations and methodes arguments are hard cached. The action shoulden't fire the exception, if you allow, like you do, that the argument could be null so im afraid that extbase diden't notice that for some cache reason.

Sorry i can not comment i don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: I deleted th annotations for remove this constraint for now, but I had the annotations generates by Extension Builder for `editAction`. You two give me the idea of use the UID, I will try it.